# React Native Android TV - No Now Playing notification [card] and DPad Functionality missing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-tv

I have published a react native application to google play store for Android Mobile and android tv. App successfully published for Android Mobile but rejected for Android Tv. For tv, I have received notification for:

> No Now Playing notification [card]"
> Your App does not contain a "Now Playing" notification [card] for when the user has selected the HOME button within the app. Please refer to our Displaying a Now Playing Card documentation for more details.

> Missing DPad functionality
> Your app requires user interaction for menus or app navigation. Please make sure that all menus and app navigation are fully functional using a DPad. Please refer to our DPAD Control and Hardware Declaration documentation.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for AndroidTV?

Comment: @AyberkAnılAtsız only find missing DPad Functionality issue

Comment: Thx I fixed both of them  thx

Comment: @AyberkAnılAtsız can you provide Answer of this question ?

Comment: DPad functionality is the accessible problem for example you have a button on the view but users can not click it. Now Playing card is the background playing video or sound problem. If your app is in the background state you have two options. 1 Stop video or sound when the app in the background. 2 fill the now playing card fields.

Answer (score 0):

for DPAD i know solution in java

1. Used this code

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

```
    /*   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);*/

    // When using DPad, show all the OSD so that focus can move freely
    // from/to ActionBar to/from PlayerController
    switch (keyCode) {

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP_LEFT:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP_RIGHT:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN_LEFT:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN_RIGHT:
            return false;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            Log.e("LoginChooserActivity", "movieIndex : ");

            return false;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            Log.d(TAG, "keyCode List" + keyCode);
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }


    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

2. for this you need to exit exoplayer while background playing